# What's the proper way to declare an attribute to be false?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

In HTML5, you can add the attribute `draggable` to any element -- it works like `checked`; it doesn't require a value. If you do want to specify a value (e.g. to make it valid XML), I think the official standard syntax is `checked="checked"`, but other things work too (including `checked=""` and `checked="false"`, confusingly). The standard way to make it ‘false’ is not to include the attribute at all.

`<img>` elements seem to be ‘draggable’ by default (even if you don't include a `draggable` attribute) ­– that's why you get the 'ghost' image effect when you drag regular images in web pages. You get this same effect on non-`img` elements if you mark them `draggable`.

So how do you disable it on `img` elements? You can set the property to false in JavaScript. But what about in the HTML?

(From experimenting, I know that `draggable="false"` seems to work in Chrome ­– is that a standard syntax that works everywhere? If so, why doesn't `checked="false"` work the same way?)

Comment: @Closer: How on earth is this question off topic???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, [W3C says](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-draggable-attribute) you're right; "true", "false" and "auto" *should* work (not to say it will everywhere).

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/nwellcome/DRSbc/ for to experiment with in different browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look [here](http://simon.html5.org/html-elements) (scroll to 'Global Attributes' and click `draggable`).

> All HTML elements may have the draggable content attribute set. The
>   draggable attribute is an enumerated attribute. It has three states.
>   The first state is true and it has the keyword true. The second state
>   is false and it has the keyword false. The third state is auto; it has
>   no keywords but it is the missing value default.
>
> The true state means the element is draggable; the false state means
>   that it is not. The auto state uses the default behavior of the user
>   agent.

So the answer is: to disable the draggable attribute for a HTML5 element, use `draggable="false"`